# Qlikview - calculate number days between two dates except sunday

Tags: date, qlikview

how can I calculate number of days between two dates except sunday.
I want to calculate  number of days between

```
date1 = 17-08-2016;
date2 = 3-09-2016;
```

I try

```
NetWorkDays(date1, date2)
```

but include include only working days...and I want to include working days and Saturday...

Any idea?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) post for how to ask better questions, which will help people give you better answers. In particular, add the code of what you've already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per *Ralf Becher* on the QlikView Community site, add this line to your load script:

```
floor(((Date2 - Date1)+1)/7)*6 + mod((Date2 - Date1)+1,7) 

+ if(Weekday(Date1) + mod((Date2 - Date1)+1,7) < 7, 0, -1) as Workingdays_6
```

then use Workingdays_6 in your count.

[More details, including example qvw](https://community.qlik.com/thread/71618)